# South Korea Exit Requirements

Tags: customs-and-immigration, south-korea

I have an F2 visa in South Korea on my Canadian passport, which has expired and in the process of renewal.  I do have to travel, and was thinking to do so on my other, and Dutch passport. Is South Korea Immigration requiring to exit the country on the same passport one came in with?

Answer (score 2):

All the articles online are telling to use the same document to enter and exit the country. If your travel is urgent, the Canadian embassy can provide you with a [limited validity travel document](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports/security/limited-validity-travel-document.html) that you can use.

I am curious how it worked out for your situation.

Ps. make sure to update your new passport information in the immigration office within 15 days of receiving it.